# Can I have a thread shutdown listener with Spring @Async?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, asynchronous

I want to change existing asynchronous, multi-threaded "post a log and forget"  logging service with Spring approach, using [@Async](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/). I have currently implemented it using `ExecutorService` and `ThreadFactory`.

Writing log entry needs to make remote call. The threads in this application use resources that are expensive to open and must be closed in time. They are not thread safe.

Hence I currently use the `ThreadFactory`, overriding the `run` method of the provided thread to open the thread local resources on startup and close them on return.

I need the same functionality with @Async. The provided tutorial does not give any clue if this is even possible.

How to run a code to open the thread-local resources on startup of the thread, and close on the end of the thread when the thread is created by Spring as a result of the @Async annotation?

This should not be done just on every call of such method.

Comment: Async methods are also executed by an Executor, that you're free to configure and provide yourself. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html and http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncConfigurer.html

Comment: If I need to create the same Executor myself, then put in the same thread factory, I actually drag in all existing code plus some Spring in addition. This probably makes a program only more complex and may only make sense if there are numerous different async methods over code, the invocation would be simpler. Sad if there is no other approach.

Comment: This a correct answer, from another side. Please convert the comment into answer so I could accept it.